# length of an array of function pointers

Tags: c

Is there a safe way to get the length of an array of function pointers?

Would the following work?

```
sizeof((uintptr_t)(*fp) / sizeof(uintptr_t)(*fp[0]))
```

Comment: At least it wouldn't work as you intend. Keep an eye on your parentheses. And please show the declaration of `fp`.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of element type, the standard idiom for the length of an array is:

```
#define countof(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))
```

This will work only if `a` is an actual array, i.e. declared as `TYPE a[...]`. If `a` is a pointer to `TYPE` that was created from an array, such as by passing the array to the function, the above macro will produce an incorrect result.

I suspect your code is the result of such a confusion. It dereferences `fp`, which is only correct if `fp` is a pointer to the array, and not if it's a pointer to an array element.

Answer (score 1):

Not a dynamically allocated array and not through a pointer to the array (which would by definition exclude dynamically allocated arrays).

`sizeof(apointer)` will return the size of the pointer not the size of the buffer it points to. There is no way in C for `sizeof` to know that the pointer points to an array or just a single element (which really is an array of 1).

If you do `sizeof(*apointer)` it will return the size of a single element (or the first element in the array) because again, there is no way in C for sizeof to know that the pointer points to an array or just a single element.